# How do you return a vector iterator from a variable in a templated class?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm trying to return an iterator for a vector in a templated class (I'm not sure if that makes a difference, but I've read that may, so I thought I'd mention it).  The problem is that I get an error about C++ not supporting default-int when I try this.  I've looked online and from what I can see in forums and explanaions, I don't think I'm *that* far off, it just won't compile.

```
template<class T>
class Table
{
public:
  ...

  vector<shared_ptr<vector<T>>>::iterator GetRowIterator();
  //vector<shared_ptr<vector<CellValueType> > >::const_iterator GetRowIterator();

  ...
protected:

  vector<shared_ptr<vector<CellValueType> > > data;  //outside vector is rows, inside vector is columns

  ...
};

vector<shared_ptr<vector<T> > >::const_iterator Table<T>::GetRowIterator()
{
  return data.begin();
}
```

The errors that I get are:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetRowIterator'

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

*Edit:*
Changed the end angle brackets so they are not as close together - same error.
Any thoughts as to why this is occurring?
As always, thanks for advice/help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also remember to use typename when declaring the template-dependent return type:

```
typename vector< shared_ptr< vector< T > > >::iterator GetRowIterator();
```

and the method definition

```
typename vector< shared_ptr< vector< T > > >::const_iterator Table<T>::GetRowIterator()
{
  return data.begin();
}
```

Notice also that when defining a template class method outside the class definition, you have to use the template keyword:

```
template <class T> typename vector< shared_ptr< vector< T > > >::const_iterator Table<T>::GetRowIterator()
    {
      return data.begin();
    }
```

So that the compiler can know what the T is about.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.  This is the first time I've used iterators in a template class, so this was a very useful learning experience :)

Answer (score 3):

This part here:

```
vector<shared_ptr<vector<T>>>
```

It is a problem with the C++ syntax you can not put >> together like that.

```
vector<shared_ptr<vector<T> > >
```

This is a problem that is being addressed by the new standard.

Because the lexer is the first stage of the compiler it sees the >>> as a shift left operator followed by >. Thus you are getting syntax errors in your code. To supress this problem you just need to add white space between the > when closing templates.

Comment: In recent (post-VS2003) MSVC that is not a problem, it recognizes the closing angle brackets correctly.

Comment: Wasn't the root of the problem, but a good rule of thumb.  Thanks for the advice! +1